# Not able to fetch age_range and gender even after getting approval from facebook in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have permissions to access gender and age from Facebook but when I try to fetch while login I only end up getting the public profile and nothing else. I will write the response and the request here.

//Request

```
FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender, age_range"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                })
```

//Response

```
{
    email = "";
    "first_name" =;
    id = 00;
    "last_name" = "";
    name = "";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            height = 200;
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "";
            width = 200;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: What permissions did you ask the user for?

Comment: I asked for age_range and user_gender

Comment: Then debug your access token to find out if they are actually granted.

Comment: I tested my facebook id with the graph API on facebook but it wasn't being displayed even there.

Comment: Works totally fine for me, as long as the required permissions have been granted.

Comment: I don't get it. The age and gender. It is really surprising.

Comment: It was a small mistake from my side. Now it works very well.

Comment: I'm issuing the same problem! damn!